# Python Selenium xPath select from div class a rel

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
<div class='into'>
    <div class="state  " rel="AA" style="width:80px;">AA (1028)</div>
    <div class="state  " rel="BB" style="width:80px;">BB (307)</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to select one of elements `rel="AA"` or `rel="BB"` to click on it, tried several ways. The most usable idea was:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='into']/[text()='AA']").click()
```

However there is a number after the text what is various.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='into']/[rel='AA']").click()
```

And this not works.

Comment: Try @rel instead of just rel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `xpath`

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='into']/div[@rel='CA']").click()
```

Also can use `normalize-space`method to omit the spaces in your class name like below -

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[normalize-space(@class)='state'][@rel='AA']").click()
```

Comment: Unable to locate, also tried:
//div[@class='into']/div[@class='state  '][@rel='CA']

Comment: is there spaces in your `class="state"` ?

Comment: can you try `.//div[@class='into']/div[@rel='CA'] `

Comment: Yep! It works. Thank you! :) Could you clarify what . made?

Comment: Actually there is spaces in your classname that's why it preventing you to find the match

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your example with text() then you could use either of the following:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='into']/div[contains(text(), 'AA')]").click()
```

or

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='into']/div[starts-with(text(), 'AA')]").click()
```

otherwise use the answer given by @lauda and use @rel to declare it as an attribute

Comment: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression. For both three tries

Comment: Ah, I forgot the second div, that is most likely the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you need your `XPath` to match one of elements with attributes `rel="AA"` **or** `rel="BB"` (in case one of them might not be present on page) then try below:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='into']/div[@rel="AA" or @rel="BB"]").click()
```